# Error while trying to parse json into R

Tags: json, r, text, jsonlite

I have recently started using R and have a task regarding parsing json in R to get a non-json format. For this, i am using the **"fromJSON()"** function. I have tried to parse json as a text file. It runs successfully when i do it with just a single row entry. But when I try it with multiple row entries, i get the following error:

```
 fromJSON("D:/Eclairs/Printing/test3.txt")
Error in feed_push_parser(readBin(con, raw(), n), reset = TRUE) : 
  lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                     [{'CategoryType':'dining','City':
                     (right here) ------^

> fromJSON("D:/Eclairs/Printing/test3.txt")
Error in feed_push_parser(readBin(con, raw(), n), reset = TRUE) : 
  parse error: trailing garbage
          "mumbai","Location":"all"}]  [{"JourneyType":"Return","Origi
                     (right here) ------^

> fromJSON("D:/Eclairs/Printing/test3.txt")
Error in feed_push_parser(readBin(con, raw(), n), reset = TRUE) : 
  parse error: after array element, I expect ',' or ']'
          :"mumbai","Location":"all"}  {"JourneyType":"Return","Origin
                     (right here) ------^
```

The above errors are due to three different formats in which i tried to parse the json text, but the result was the same, only the location suggested by changed. 
Please help me to identify the cause of this error or if there is a more efficient way o performing the task.

The original file that i have is an excel sheet with multiple columns and one of those columns consists of json text. The way i tried right now is by extracting just the json column and converting it to a tab separated text and then parsing it as:

```
fromJSON("D:/Eclairs/Printing/test3.txt")
```

Please also suggest if this can be done more efficiently. I need to map all the columns in the excel to the non-json text as well.

```
Example: 
[{"CategoryType":"dining","City":"mumbai","Location":"all"}]
[{"CategoryType":"reserve-a-table","City":"pune","Location":"Kothrud,West Pune"}]
[{"Destination":"Mumbai","CheckInDate":"14-Oct-2016","CheckOutDate":"15-Oct-2016","Rooms":"1","NoOfPax":"3","NoOfAdult":"3","NoOfChildren":"0"}]
```

Comment: It might help if you show the full JSON, or at least a full fragment of the portion which is erroring out.

Comment: I'm guessing you're missing a comma between the JSON objects

Comment: I am not putting a comma between different rows, as have converted it to a tab separated txt file. Is there a need to place commas, because then i'll have to manually modify the data...

Comment: Please include examples of the json files you try to parse, without that we are left as guessing as you are. In addition, you can validate your json on sites like [json lint](http://jsonlint.com/). Simply paste your json into the text box and you'll hear if the json is correct or not.

Comment: Have added 3 rows of the file am trying to parse. The entire file is a tab separated text file.

Comment: You should post the output of `dput(head(df$colname))` replacing `df` and `colname` with the name of the data frame you read the Excel file in as and the column name of the column with JSON data. That implies you should read in the entire Excel file. Hand-manipulating data (even for extraction) is not a repeatable task nor is it very efficient and is seriously prone to error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider reading in the text line by line with `readLines()`, iteratively saving the JSON dataframes to a growing list:

```
library(jsonlite)

con <- file("C:/Path/To/Jsons.txt", open="r")

jsonlist <- list()
while (length(line <- readLines(con, n=1, warn = FALSE)) > 0) {
  jsonlist <- append(jsonlist, list(fromJSON(line)))
}
close(con)

jsonlist    
# [[1]]
#   CategoryType   City Location
# 1       dining mumbai      all

# [[2]]
#      CategoryType City          Location
# 1 reserve-a-table pune Kothrud,West Pune

# [[3]]
#   Destination CheckInDate CheckOutDate Rooms NoOfPax NoOfAdult NoOfChildren
# 1      Mumbai 14-Oct-2016  15-Oct-2016     1       3         3            0
```